# Are collapse all and expand all functionality provided by EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is it possible to programmatically collapse and expand the tree view of the project browser in EA?

Comment: Share some code which you've tried so far

Answer (score 1):

To show an item use

```
Repository.ShowInProjectView (object Item)
```

So if you want to expand a package view you need to issue the above for the first element in a package. To expand more (recursive) you need to do that for all first leaves of nested packages/elements.

To collapse a view you need to issue

```
Repository.RefreshModelView (long PackageID)
```

Comment: To verify, until the answer is confirmed, it works! (Tested in EA 1307)

Comment: @Kolky Thanks for the confirmation. The OP is obviously an ask-once poster ;-)